# How to use local html page as desktop/background

Tags: windows-7, html, desktop, desktop-customization

On a windows 7 computer how might one set the desktop to be a webpage. I want to have a local html file that I can edit as needed. Then windows should show that file as the background for the desktop but I should be able to click on links and interact with the page. Certain links would launch certain programs.

So I want to go this route because there is no way that I know to corral a group of icons to a certain part of the screen. When I disconnect and reconnect monitors and such things move around. No icons are forced to stay in part of the group they are supposed to be a part of. At this point I just have folders on the desktop with the app links in those folders. This means I have to open multiple folders to get where I want.

Any ideas on the html angle or other ideas on how to accomplish this?

thanks,

bye.

Answer (score 3):

[BackgroundPage](http://ciaccodavi.de/BackgroundPage/) by Reddit user [forkafork](https://www.reddit.com/r/LivingBackgrounds/comments/5kgjrx/software_backgroundpage_using_a_web_page_as_an/) is a **FREE** solution. **His documentation explicitly states that it works with local html files.** It unfortunately runs ontop of desktop icons, but  the desktop icons can be revealed again by clicking Windows' "Show Desktop" button in the taskbar.

---

[Plastuer](http://plastuer.com/) allows GIF, video, and webpage backgrounds. **But I wasn't able to make 100% sure that it works with local html files**. It has a very professional and slick interface and **preserves your desktop icons**. Here is an installation video guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO6Uy8qOPjU

The software is not free and is PWYW (Pay What You Want). The minimum it allows you to pay (at the time of this post) is **$2.00 USD**.

---

Here is a guide on installing a **FREE** 3rd-party app called "[WallpaperWebPage](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/WallpaperWebPage.shtml)" on Windows 10:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/web-page-wallpaper-windows/

Unfortunately, using this software gets rid of your desktop icons.

Comment: Great finds! Unfortunately, I am not able to buy plastuer in my country, so I hope these alternatives work out.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a Windows feature called Active Desktop that would let you use a webpage as a background, local or otherwise. But the feature was removed from Windows Vista and onward due to potential security risks, I believe.

So, I'd suggest looking for a 3rd party program that can emulate the Active Desktop behaviour.

Hope this helps in some way,

-R

Comment: Saying there used to be a feature and suggesting that the OP look for a 3rd party solution is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @fixer1234 I disagree. The name "Active Desktop" let me google it and find [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/190228).

Comment: @Chipperyman: How does that make this an answer to the question?