# Is it possible to set an html5 file as desktop background on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, desktop-customization

I don't think it can be difficult to understand the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: This feature has been completely removed from Windows for over a decade for security reasons.

Comment: [I forgot to link to the existing question](http://superuser.com/questions/895504/how-to-use-local-html-page-as-desktop-background)

Comment: @Dave, I think you're to much talker, non in a offensive way. First of all: Raumhound had specified what I'm trying to get, which is not possible. I said "it might be hard to understand" 'cause since windows 8 I don't see this feature anymore, and maybe somebody created some hack for it, even more, you can't come to say "be specific", after someone gave me alternatives, so please, be concise next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is *possible*.  Way back in the day MS had [Active Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Desktop) that could display webpage(s) as wallpaper.  However, this has been long since discontinued.

There are programs that appear to have this functionality.  Just googling I found some.  Here is [one](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/display-interactive-webpage-wallpaper-windows-desktop-wallpaperwebpage).  I dont know if it works, you may get lucky.

Comment: I tested it and it is a fiasco, what it does is to set an webbrowser component (I supposed) to browsing the url requested.

Comment: did you try googling for others?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I actually see certain configs on the gpedit.msc which still make credible that possibility, even if not work